# Vrais et Faux jumeaux (féminin)

Tags: usage, adjectifs, pluriel

Quelle tournure emploie-t-on au  féminin ?

> Ces deux garçons sont des vrais/faux jumeaux.
>
> Ces deux filles sont des vraies/fausses jumelles.

Est-ce correct la dernière proposition ?

Comment: [Une bonne réponse déjà](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31545/13100). Je note que dans mon expérience, l'emploi des termes *jumeaux/jumelles identiques/non-identiques* est un peu plus commun et à mon sens moins ambigu *(ce sont de vrais jumeaux!*, entendra-t-on parfois de personnes se ressemblant, liées ou non par le sang, la ressemblance n'atteignant cependant jamais celle extrêmement troublante que partagent les jumeaux/jumelles identiques).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sans ambiguïté :

> Ces deux filles sont des vraies/fausses jumelles.

« jumelle » est le féminin de « jumeau ».

Comment: Would "le masculin l'emporte …” when referring to opposite sex dizygotic twins: e.g., “ Ces deux-là [frère et sœur] sont des faux jumeaux !”? Thanks.

Comment: @PapaPoule: Yes. « une sœur et un frère jumeaux »